# How to make Anjuta DevStudio prompt tips like Eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ide, anjuta

I used to use Eclipse to develop Java and when I used the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, Eclipse would prompt some tips for coding.

When it comes to Anjuta DevStudio, can it do the same job?

If not, anyone can introduce me to an IDE for C and C++ development on Linux?

Comment: How about... Eclipse? It is available for GNU/Linux too.

Comment: Why don't you use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-linux-developers-includes-incubating-components/heliosr) since you're already familiar with that IDE?

Comment: because the eclipse just treat the c source as plain text file.it is something that i can not accept

Comment: Have you installed the [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) plugins in Eclipse?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24109/78845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question, according to the [Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-keybindings.htm) 'Ctrl + /' maps to the source action Comment.

That doesn't look like auto suggest to me ?

That said, the GtkSourceView version of Anjuta appears to not support Comment / Uncomment for some unspecified reason according to a Mailing List post, apparently the Scintilla version does however. There was talk of working around this using a Python plugin but I don't think anything eventuated from that discussion.

Regarding code completion in Anjuta , it should automatically provide symbol completion , and call tips along with class members if it has indexed your symbols properly, this should be done as you are typing (code-ahead).

Regarding your If not clause, see the following relevant StackOverflow Posts

- [C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)
- [What is a good Linux IDE for code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780837/what-is-a-good-linux-ide-for-code-completion)
- [Good C++ Debugging/IDE Environment for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596575/good-c-debugging-ide-environment-for-linux)
- [Best C++ development environment in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658983/best-c-development-environment-in-linux)

and various others that were closed for being duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to forget about Anjuta and switch to KDevelop4 - it is much faster than Eclipse and it has much more "bells and wistles" than Eclipse. Once you try it I'm pretty sure that you will never look back on Anjuta :)

Comment: That is my (and not only my) opinion. KDevelop is probably not the best choice for Java, but for C/C++/PHP definitely yes. Tooltips are much faster (and in Technicolor :)), not ot mention that syntax highlighting is better then Anjuta. I tried using Anjuta quite a few times and I always returned to KDevelop.

Comment: Another good editor IMHO is Qt Creator, you can use it as code editor also for non QT projects. It's very fast and reactive, especially for the code hints.

Comment: That was really a good tip, I just switched to KDevelop after I read your suggestion. It is much more convenient especially the code completition and the build in documentation function that allows to read the comments above a function.

Comment: KDevelop won't show GTK IDEs.  Anjuta will.  KDevelop is also focused on Qt.  Anjuta is focused on GTK.  That said, I agree KDevelop5 outdoes Anjuta by quite a bit.  But what should those of us who need GTK use?  Gnome Develop doesn't seem to have the features needed.  ??